# Testing python programs without using python shell

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to easily test my python programs without constantly using the python shell since each time the program is modified you have to quit, re-enter the python shell and import the program again. I am using a 2012 Macbook pro with OSX. I have the following code:

```
import sys

def read_strings(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        return file.read().split('>')[1:0]

file1 = sys.argv[1]
filename = read_strings(file1)
```

Essentially I would like to read into and split a txt file containing:

> id1>id2>id3>id4

I am entering this into my command line:

> pal-nat184-102-127:python_stuff ceb$ python3 program.py string.txt

However when I try the sys.argv approach on the command line my program returns nothing. Is this a good approach to testing code, could anyone point me in the correct direction?

This is what I would like to happen:

> pal-nat184-102-127:python_stuff ceb$ python3 program.py string.txt
>
> ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']

Comment: 1. Quit from where and re-import where? 2. Yes, running script/test suite from the shell is a common method of testing. 3. Of course it does not return anything, because you do not tell it to return anything — what is the result you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never do anything with the result of `read_strings`. Try:

```
print(read_strings(file1))
```

Comment: Minor note: in Python 3, print is no longer a statement, it's a function.  You need to use parens: print(read_strings(file1)) instead of print read_strings(file1).

Comment: Thanks, I've yet to even touch Python 3 so I appreciate the heads up!

Comment: I see. When I use print(read_strings(file1)) the output is the following: []...however I am hoping to get this output: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'].

Comment: @cebach561 I think the slice you're doing after the call to `.split()` is the problem. Remove the `[1:0]` at the end. Does that fix it for you?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this a piece at a time:

> However when I try the sys.argv approach on the command line my
>   program returns nothing

The final result of your program is that it writes a string into the variable filename.  It's a little strange to have a program "return" a value.  Generally, you want a program to print it's something out or save something to a file.  I'm guessing it would ease your debugging if you modified your program by adding,

```
print (filename)
```

at the end: you'd be able to see the result of your program.

> could anyone point me in the correct direction?

One other debugging note: It can be useful to write your .py files so that they can be run both independently at the command line or in a python shell.  How you've currently structured your code, this will work semi-poorly.  (Starting a shell and then importing your file will cause an error because sys.argv[1] isn't defined.)

A solution to this is to change your the bottom section of your code as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file1 = sys.argv[1]
    filename = read_strings(file1)
```

The if guard at the top says, "If running as a standalone script, then run what's below me.  If you imported me from some place else, then do not execute what's below me."

Feel free to follow up below if I misinterpreted your question.